# Only the first added item to struct is uploaded to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, struct

I want to upload all info in my Struct to Firebase, but I´m only getting the first item added to upload. I'm also displaying the Struct in a `tableView` and this works great.

**Struct File:**

```
struct Products {
    var name: String = ""
    var amount = Int()
}

 var prodItems : [Products] = []
```

**The struct is populated with a button:**
(The `name` variable is being passed from previous `ViewController`)

```
 @IBAction func addItemButton(_ sender: UIButton){

        if let index = i prodItems.index(where: { $0.name == name })   {
            prodItems[index].amount += 1
        } else {
            prodItems.append(Products(name: name, amount: 1))
        }
    }
```

**The struct populates a tableView like this:**

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell") as! SummaryTableViewCell

name = prodItems[indexPath.row].name
         let amount = prodItems[indexPath.row].amount

        cell.summaryLabel.text = "\(amount) \(name)"

        return cell
    }
```

All of the above works fine, the problem comes when I try to upload to Firebase.
**I'm trying to upload to Firebase like so:**

```
 @IBAction func orderButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for items in prodItems {    
      let firebaseData = "\(items.amount) \(items.name)"    
      let data = ["Uploaded" : timeStamp, "Order" : firebaseData] as [String : Any]
            self.ref?.child("Orders").child(childByAutoId).updateChildValues(data, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }    
                    break
        }

    }
```

With this setup I can only get the first item added to upload to Firebase.
If the user first adds 1 pair of shoes, and then 1 pair of jeans to the cart, Firebase will only get 1 pair of shoes.
How can I get Firebase to receive the whole order?

*EDIT*
[image: New databasestructure]

I would like it to be: ...`"Order:" 2 Shoes, 1 Jeans, 3 Hats"`
Without the 0,1,2 and so on following the child "Order"

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of [`updateChildValues`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) which will update the whole value at specific child, you are calling it inside the for loop. Try once creating array of dictionary and set the whole array directly. Like this.

```
let arrayOfDic = prodItems.map({ ["Uploaded" : timeStamp, "Order" : "\($0.amount) \($0.name)"] })
self.ref?.child("Orders").child(childByAutoId).updateChildValues(arrayOfDic, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error!)
    }    
})
```

**Edit:** If you want to set order as a string value then set it like this.

```
let order = array.map({ String(format: "%d %@", $0.amount, $0.name) }).joined(separator: ", ")
let dic = ["Uploaded" : timeStamp, "Order" : order] 
self.ref?.child("Orders").child(childByAutoId).updateChildValues(dic, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error!)
    }    
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now its uploading the whole order, but the database structure is a bit off. I have updated my initial question with some more info

Comment: @Anvil Please check edited answer to set order in way you want